# Are variables in script type = "module" "invisible"?

Tags: javascript, html, object, ecmascript-6, module

Say I have the following code:

```js
//myjs.js
let testingVisibility = "hello";
```

```html
<script type = "module" src = "myjs.js"></script>
```

When I want to access `testingVisibility` variable through the console in Firefox, `testingVisibility` variable is not declared.

Comment: if you `export` it, it should be available.

Comment: @Derek I see. So that's how it is. All variables and functions inside a `script type = "module"` are not available unless exported and imported to another certain script, right? And as the importing script also has to have the `type = "module"` attached, I won't ever be able to access said variables through my console, ever?

Comment: you can also export it to global space, like `window.testingVisibility  = testingVisibility`, it's then somewhat like a global.

Comment: Every module has its own scope.

Comment: @FelixKling I see! So basically, a module kinda creates its own function-like scope, meaning any variables declared by both `var` and `let` can't be accessed outside said module. These variables are typically not accessible outside said function-like scope (if we're talking about functions, the only way to get their values would be returning them). However, with modules, we can easily provide accessibility to other modules (function-like scope) by using export and import. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Right. Scope is really just an "area" in the program that associates a name with a value (variables). Normal scripts are all evaluated in the same scope, the global scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you haven't exported them - exports are the whole point of `type="module"`. Just use a normal script:

```
<script src="myjs"></script>
```

If you want to use `type="module"`, then export something from `myjs`:

```
export let testingVisibility = "hello";
```

Then in your HTML;

```
<script type="module">
    import { testingVisibility } from "./myjs";
    //Do stuff with testingVisibility
</script>
```

Comment: That means I won't be able to access the variables in my modules through my browser's console, right?

Comment: @RichardW right, as long as you don't explicitly assign them to `window`.